# My program of speller.c is not compiling pset5

Tags: c, dictionary, compiler-errors, cs50

When I run my program i get these 2 errors and not sure why

The error

```
dictionary.c:87:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'words_counter'
        words_counter++;
        ^
dictionary.c:97:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'words_counter'
    return words_counter;
           ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:3: speller] Error 1
```

The code

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1500;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int index = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[index];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word) ==0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        //Move cursor to next node
        cursor = cursor -> next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    // Ref of hash function: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/cs50-good-hash-function-for-pset5-speller/38755
    int hash = 600;
    while (*word != '\0')
    {
        hash = ((hash << 4 ) + (int) (*word)) % N;
        word++;
    }
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Read strings from file
    // define word
    char word [LENGTH + 1];
    int index;
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Creating new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Copies word to the node
        strcpy (n->word, word);
        // Obtaining index to hash word
        index = hash(word);
        n -> next = table[index];
        table[index] = n;
        words_counter++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return words_counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    //Free nodes in each linked list
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *tmp = cursor;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor-> next;
            free (tmp);
            tmp = cursor;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I defined words_counter and it compiled but it seems I did not pass check50 by 2 mistakes:
the code

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1500;
unsigned words_counter;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int index = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[index];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word) == 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        //Move cursor to next node
        cursor = cursor -> next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    // Ref of hash function: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/cs50-good-hash-function-for-pset5-speller/38755
    int hash = 600;
    while (*word != '\0')
    {
        hash = ((hash << 4 ) + (int) (*word)) % N;
        word++;
    }
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Read strings from file
    // define word
    char word [LENGTH + 1];
    int index;
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Creating new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Copies word to the node
        strcpy (n->word, word);
        // Obtaining index to hash word
        index = hash(word);
        n -> next = table[index];
        table[index] = n;
        words_counter++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return words_counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    //Free nodes in each linked list
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *tmp = cursor;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor-> next;
            free (tmp);
            tmp = cursor;


        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

the mistakes:

:) dictionary.c exists

:) speller compiles

:( handles most basic words properly

expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."

:) handles min length (1-char) words

:) handles max length (45-char) words

:) handles words with apostrophes properly

:( spell-checking is case-insensitive

expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."

:) handles substrings properly

:) program is free of memory errors

I am not sure how to handle these 2

Comment: erm.... because `words_counter` is actually undefined?

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory.  All variables in C must be defined before they are used. Can you point to where you think the `words_counter` variable is defined?

Comment: what is `words_counter`? Looks like it's supposed to be an `unsigned int`, but you haven't defined it anywhere in your code, so we don't know and neither does the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `words_counter` is used as the global variable in your code, so define it in the same place as other global objects:

```
const unsigned int N = 1500;
unsigned words_counter;
```